# Performing simple arithmetic operations and displaying the answer using Label

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I have the following in textboxes and labels:

```
 txtAmount1_1
 txtAmount1_2
 txtAmount1_3

 txtAmount2_1
 txtAmount2_2
 txtAmount2_3

 lblTotal1
 lblTotal2

 lblGrandTotal
```

I want to display the sum of txtAmount1_1, txtAmount1_2 and txtAmount1_3 to lblTotal1, and the sum of txtAmount2_1, txtAmount2_2, and txtAmount2_3 to lblTotal2, and the sum of lblTotal1 and lblTotal2 to lblGrandTotal. So I entered the following codes:

```
  Private Sub txtAmount1_1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount1_1.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount1_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

 Private Sub txtAmount1_2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount1_2.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount1_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

 Private Sub txtAmount1_3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount1_3.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount1_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

 Private Sub txtAmount2_1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount2_1.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount2_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

 Private Sub txtAmount2_2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount2_2.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount2_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

 Private Sub txtAmount2_3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount2_3.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount2_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

 Private Sub lblTotal1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblTotal1.Click
    Dim a As Decimal
    Dim b As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount1_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)

    b = Val(lblTotal1.Text) + Val(lblTotal2.Text)
    lblGrandTotal.Text = Val(b)
End Sub

 Private Sub lblTotal2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblTotal2.Click
    Dim a As Decimal
    Dim b As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount2_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)

    b = Val(lblTotal1.Text) + Val(lblTotal2.Text)
    lblGrandTotal.Text = Val(b)
End Sub

Private Sub lblGrandTotal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblGrandTotal.Click
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(lblTotal1.Text) + Val(lblTotal2.Text)
    lblGrandTotal.Text = Val(a)
End Sub
```

The lblTotal1 and lblTotal2 works fine (by that I mean it displays the sum of the values from the textboxes correctly), but lblGrandTotal doesn't work (does not display the sum of lblTotal1 and lblTotal2). Why is that so? Is there something wrong with my codes? Then where?

Comment: You are adding up values on textAmount1_1, textAmount1_2, textAmount1_ 3 on TextChanged event but, you are adding lblTotal1 and lblTotal2 on Click so, event will fire on click. And it will add up values on click try clicking lblTotal1 or lblTotal2 once u have values in both.

Comment: dont use `val` and start accepting the answers people provide you

Comment: When I clicked the labels, an error occured. `Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'Label'.` When I try to change the _Click event to _TextChanged event, it displays another error. `An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'Label'.`

Comment: @Plutonix say that because you don't know how many answers I have tried and ended up in failure. that's why I ask because I am a beginner and not yet familiar with everything about vb. and if the answers given to me were not effective? of course I will have to look for other answers again until I understand what I am doing wrong. and you helped a lot from my previous questions. for that, thank you very much.

Comment: i say that because you have asked 6 questions, gotten 8 answers and  clicked the checkmark for none of them  http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think your program is a little bit messy, i don't see much the concept the you want, but i try to modify some of your program or i think this is what you want...

[image]

```
Private Sub txtAmount1_1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount1_1.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount1_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

Private Sub txtAmount1_2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount1_2.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount1_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

Private Sub txtAmount1_3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount1_3.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount1_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

Private Sub txtAmount2_1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount2_1.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount2_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_3.Text)
    lblTotal2.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

Private Sub txtAmount2_2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount2_2.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount2_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_3.Text)
    lblTotal2.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

Private Sub txtAmount2_3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAmount2_3.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount2_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_3.Text)
    lblTotal2.Text = Val(a)
End Sub

Private Sub lblTotal1_TextChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblTotal1.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal
    Dim b As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount1_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount1_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)

    b = Val(lblTotal1.Text) + Val(lblTotal2.Text)
    lblGrandTotal.Text = Val(b)
End Sub

Private Sub lblTotal2_TextChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblTotal2.TextChanged
    Dim a As Decimal
    Dim b As Decimal

    a = Val(txtAmount2_1.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_2.Text) + Val(txtAmount2_3.Text)
    lblTotal1.Text = Val(a)

    b = Val(lblTotal1.Text) + Val(lblTotal2.Text)
    lblGrandTotal.Text = Val(b)
End Sub
```

I Notice that lblTotal2 is constant or not changing. i think that this is the same concept of lblTotal1 so i change it to add  txtAmount2_1,txtAmount2_2,txtAmount2_3 then i change the click event on your label to Text change because the event will only trigger when you click the label, i know that you want is to automatically display the sum of all the textbox and display the final total of the two lblTotal1 and lblTotal2...

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I found out that I just mistyped some textbox names that's why it doesn't sum up! silly me. I also changed _Click to _TextChanged and now it's working properly :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out my mistake already. It was a typographical error (instead of `Val(txtAmount1_1.Text)`, I just typed `Val(txtAmount1_1)`). It works fine now. And I did use Val because not using it gave me error in my codes.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @xlembouras: this is an answer to the question, even though it is a simple one.